# Using Stripes MVC for developing REST service

Tags: rest, stripes

Is it possible to expose stripes MVC controller as REST service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/) you can build *[action beans](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/ActionBean.html)* that respond to URL’s from REST services (Stripes MVC controller just dispatches the URL’s to the correct action beans).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you mean by 'REST service'?  Anyway: http://old.nabble.com/Stripes@Rest-td18354330.html